# ¿Comó generar una secuencia en progresión geométrica)

Tags: r

¿Cómo puedo generar una secuencia de números que están en progresión geométrica?

Por ejemplo la idea sería generar un vector secuencial como:

```
2,4,8,16,32,46, etc
```

Siempre hasta un número finito dado previamente.

Comment: A los eventuales revisores: esta es una pregunta muy simple, pero no quiere decir que no sea útil, Traté de mejorarla un poco.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma es la iterativa clásica, digamos que quieres unos 10 números en progresión geométrica, harías algo así:

```
cant <- 10
numeros <- c()
for (n in 1:cant) {
 numeros <- c(numeros, 2^n) 
}
```

Sin embargo, esto tiene poco sentido en R, el cual está "acostumbrado" a trabajar con vectores y puedes optar por una forma mucho más compacta y eventualmente más "performante" usando [`rep()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/rep)

```
numeros <- 2^rep(1:cant)
```

Con [`rep()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/rep) generamos un vector de 1 a 10, y luego simplemente elevamos el 2 a dicha potencia.